# library to convert CSV to XML, MYSQL, html, RSS, JSON and etc?

Tags: csv

it can be any language.

is there a library, software, or plugin that will convert the csv to the various formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use the dynamic language of my choice. Most of them have a CSV library and libraries to generate the output you want. Just a few lines and you have written it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add, you can use phpmyadmin of wamp server if you need to import well formatted csv format into mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [product](http://www.dbf2002.com/csv-converter/) that converts CSV to other formats/

You could just [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk) to do the same.

Comment: No, you can't use sed and awk for general CSV files. Only specific to your application where you know that there are no "special" cases like a "," inside a field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with developing your own library since there is always more/custom work to be done; An idea would be to firstly create a process of importing a CSV file into a database. Once its in the database you can easily query and output using the database or using a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice generic library in perl for doing conversions and treating a bunch of differenct formats (XML, CSV, HTML etc) as hashes. Even extends to direct treatment (DBI) as table data.

AnyData
https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyData